# Working with knockout.js & flipclock.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mvvm, knockout.js, flipclock

I am developing a basic time tracking chrome extension and have run into an issue integrating FlipClock.js (a jQuery plugin) with Knockout.

The goal is to have a foreach binding template the relevant HTML and instantiate a FlipClock; up to a total of four FlipClocks. Currently, I'm getting the following error from FlipClock: 'Trying to start timer when countdown already at 0'. My guess is that this is short for "Knockout is destroying your flipclock when the viewmodel updates."

My question is this: Is there a way to prevent the flipclocks from being updated with knockouts viewmodel?

I've pasted in the relevant code below.

JS:

```
function Timer (name) {

    //Declaring Observables, etc.
    var timer = this;
        timer.name = ko.observable(name);
        timer.format = function () {
            return name.replace(/ /g, '');
        };
        timer.key = (timer.format()+ Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000000000)+1));
        timer.clock = $('#' + timer.key + '').FlipClock({countdown: false, autoStart: true, ClockFace: 'HourlyCounter'});
        timer.started = ko.observable(false);
        timer.running = ko.observable(false);
        timer.stopped = ko.observable(false);
        timer.reset = ko.observable(false);
        timer.cleared = ko.observable(false);
        timer.value = timer.clock.getTime();
        timer.start = timer.clock.start();
        timer.stop = timer.clock.stop();
        timer.reset = timer.clock.reset();

//Time Tracker Viewmodel
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;
        self.timers = ko.observableArray([]);

    //New Timer Method
    self.createTimer = function () {
        var name = $('.projectInput').val(),
            css = name.replace(/ /g, '');
            self.timers.push(new Timer(name));
            $('.projectInput').val("");
    }
}
//Applying bindings to view model
ko.applyBindings (new ViewModel());
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="timers" data-bind="foreach: timers()">
        <div class="instance">
            <div class="timerUI">
                <div class="title" data-bind="text: name()"></div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="start button" data-bind="click: clock.start()"></div>
                    <div class="stop button" data-bind="click: clock.stop()"></div>
                    <div class="reset button" data-bind="click: clock.reset()"></div>
                    <div class="clear button" data-bind="click: $parent.clearTimer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="time" data-bind="attr: {id: key}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Timer` constructor is trying to call methods of your FlipClock before it's been instantiated. Move the line

```
timer.clock = $('#' + timer.key + '').FlipClock({countdown: false, autoStart: true, ClockFace: 'HourlyCounter'});
```

before any code that references `timer.clock` (this should have caused error messages; make sure you have your console and debugger open when you get mysterious misbehavior like this).

UPDATE

```
<div class="start button" data-bind="click: clock.start()"></div>
<div class="stop button" data-bind="click: clock.stop()"></div>
<div class="reset button" data-bind="click: clock.reset()"></div>
```

The `start`, `stop` and `reset` methods are being called *at the time your bindings are evaluated* (which means they're being called in rapid succession), not when the buttons are clicked. You need to take the parentheses off so that what's being passed is a function reference, not the result of a function invocation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it looks like I edited the code in the post incorrectly. I've updated it to better reflect what I'm working with.